# Laravel as an addon to an existing site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite

I have my site already built up in say: `http://example.com`
My Directory structure is:

```
root/
  |
  -- htdocs/    ---> This is the document root. All the front end scripts are located here.
  |  |
  |  - css/
  |  - ...
  |
  -- cms/   --> This is the backend. This site is like a cms Driven Site.
```

Now I wanted to install laravel in the back end. I want to build my CMS using laravel. But I don't want the URL to be like: `http://example.com/cms/public/`

I want it just to be: `http://example.com/cms/`

I know, I can just place all the folders outside in the document root and rename the `public` folder and change some settings to achieve what I want. But I don't want my document root to have all those files & folders and files mixed with my front end related files & folders. I want this whole thing to be separate and easy to use in other web site back end.

In order to achieve this, I have used 2 `.htaccess` files.

In the document root, I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^cms/$      cms/public/     [L]
    RewriteRule    ^cms/(.*)$  cms/public/$1   [L]
</IfModule>
```

And inside the cms folder I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$      public/     [L]
    RewriteRule    ^(.*)$  public/$1   [L]
</IfModule>
```

I am not very good at writing `.htaccess` or doing `mod_rewrite`.

Can anybody help me

Comment: Do you have ssh access? If so you can create a symlink from /home/var/app/public to home/var/public_html/cms

Comment: Yes... It's a windows server by the way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve what you want in this way:

Create a directory junction for the `public` folder from `laravel` to your backend target folder:

`mklink /J C:\www\htdocs\app-frontend\cms C:\www\htdocs\app-backend\public`

The first path is for the alias and the second path is for the *real* folder. Here `app-backend` would be the folder where `laravel` is installed to.

This is how I deal with Laravel in shared hosting.

If you were to opt for the `mod_rewrite` approach, the `.env` file will be exposed.